# Terms query with keyword

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I use `keywords` and `case_insensitive` option using https://github.com/olivere/elastic.

I could not find any examples on how to do this.

An example query of what I want:

```
GET elastic_org/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "registeredName.keyword": {
        "value": "prop org",
        "case_insensitive": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create an analyzer and use it for that situations,
look at the analyzers

[lowercase analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html)